# d3.js - the location of circle is not where it is expected. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Please see the working example of `d3.js` script below. The vertical line, `mline1` is located at x-axis value of `16000`. The line sloping down, `dline` is supposed to represent the equation
`x = 48000 - 16000*y`. The intersection of `mline1` and `dline` should occur at value of `x=16000 and y=2`. I draw a circle with center at `x=16000 and y=2`, and I expect it to be at the intersection of the two lines above. But it is not. Would really appreciate if you could help me understand this, or let me know if this is a bug in d3.js scaling behavior, or some other bug.

Thanks in advance.

**The Code**

```
<html>
<head>
      <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viz"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var paddingH = 50;
        var paddingV = 50;
        var width = 700;
        var height = 400

        cv = d3.select("#viz").append("svg:svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)

        var xs = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([0,50000])
                            .range([paddingH,width-paddingH]);

        var ys = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([0,5.5])
                            .range([height-paddingV,paddingV]);                                                                                     
        xline = cv.append("svg:line")
                    .attr("x1", xs(0))
                    .attr("x2", xs(50000))
                    .attr("y1", ys(0))
                    .attr("y2", ys(0))
                    .style("stroke", "darkgray");

        yline = cv.append("svg:line")
            .attr("x1", xs(0))
            .attr("x2", xs(0))
            .attr("y1", ys(0))
            .attr("y2", ys(5))
            .style("stroke", "darkgray");



        dline = cv.append("svg:line")
            .attr("x1", xs(0))
            .attr("y1", ys(4))
            .attr("x2", xs(48000))
            .attr("y2", ys(0))
            .style("stroke", "steelblue")
            .style("stroke-width", 2);


        mline1 = cv.append("svg:line")
            .attr("x1", xs(16000))
            .attr("y1", ys(0))
            .attr("x2", xs(16000))
            .attr("y2", ys(5))
            .style("stroke", "green");


        circleIntersect = cv.append("svg:circle")
                            .attr("cx", xs(16000))
                            .attr("cy", ys(2))
                            .attr("r",4)
                            .style("stroke", "red")
                            .style("fill", "red");


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dline` does *not* represent `x = 48000 - 16000y`; if that were the case, it should cross the y axis at a value of **3**, not 4 (`16 * 4 = 64`).

Either your `dline` should start at `y = 3`, or your circle should be at `y =~ 2.67`.

You can see for yourself [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U6mCa/).

Comment: Thanks! I don't believe I spent so much time on this stupid mistake. For some reason I was thinking that the dline intersects y-axis at value of 4. It is, of course, 3. Anyhow, thanks.

Comment: @Curious2learn: This one actually took me back; I remember totally bombing a 1-question math quiz back in school from making the same dumb mistake: thinking 48 / 16 = 4.

Comment: Wow! Same numbers. That is interesting. What are the odds?